# stack around a variabe corrupted plus programs stops after inputting certain value c++

Tags: c++

My program is meant to generate a dynamic 2d array then sort then transpose the array(swtitching columns and rows) My problem is when i input a certain value(7) for the rows and columns a stack around the variable indices becomes corrupted furthermore my code starts generating numbers that make no since i think its because it some is out of bounds please help me im relalitvely new to c++

```
//
// C++ program template
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void init_array(int ** array_in, int rows, int cols, int list[]);
void print_array(int ** array_in, int rows, int cols);
void selection_sort(int array_in[], int elements);
int ** transpose(int ** array_in, int ** array_out, int rows, int cols);
const unsigned int SIZE = 4000;
int count1 = 0;
int main(void)
{
    int rows = 0, cols = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    int**numbers = nullptr;
    int**arraytranspose = nullptr;
    cout << "Enter rows and columns" << endl;
    cin >> rows >> cols;
    int length = rows * cols;


    int list[4000] = { 0 };
    numbers = new int*[rows];
    arraytranspose = new int*[rows];

        for (k = 0; k < cols; k++)
    {
        numbers[k] = new int[cols];
        arraytranspose[k] = new int[cols];
    }
    // initialize the array with unique values
    init_array(numbers, rows, cols, list);
    print_array(numbers, rows, cols);

    selection_sort(list, count1);
    int count3 = 0;

    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < 3999; count2++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {

                if (list[count2] != 0)
                {

                    numbers[i][c] = list[count2];

                }
                count2++;
            }
        }
    }
    print_array(numbers, rows, cols);
    cout << endl << endl;

    print_array(transpose(numbers,arraytranspose,rows,cols), rows, cols);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void selection_sort(int array_in[], int elements)
{
    int index = 0, smallest = 0, hold = 0, count = 0, location = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < SIZE - 1; index++) // Loop to control number of passes
    {
        smallest = index;
        // Find the index of the smallest element
        for (location = index + 1; location < SIZE; location++)
        {
            if (array_in[location] < array_in[smallest])
            {
                smallest = location;
            } // End If

        } // End Inner for loop

        hold = array_in[smallest];
        array_in[smallest] = array_in[index];
        array_in[index] = hold;
        count++; // Count number of swaps
    }
    cout << "There were " << count << " element exchanges during the sort. " << endl << endl;
    return;
}
void init_array(int ** array_in, int rows, int cols, int list[])
{
    int j = 0, k = 0, value = 0;
    int indices[4000] = { 0 };
    count1 = 0;

    while (j < rows)
    {
        k = 0;
        while (k < cols)
        {
            value = rand() & 4000;
            if (indices[value] != 1)
            {
                array_in[j][k] = value;
                indices[value] = 1;
                list[count1] = array_in[j][k];
                k++;
                count1++;
            }

        }// end while
        j++;
    }
    return;
}
void print_array(int ** array_in, int rows, int cols)
{
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
            cout << setw(5) << array_in[j][k];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return;
}
int** transpose(int ** array_in, int ** array_out,int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            array_out[r][c] = array_in[c][r];
        }
    }

    return array_out;
}
```

Comment: Don't use manual dynamic memory allocation in C++, it is really bad style. Use `std::vector` instead. It manages memory automatically for you and you would probably not have made the error with it.

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers = new int*[rows];
arraytranspose = new int*[rows];
```

This allocates memory for a pair of arrays, an array of `rows` values.

Immediately afterwards:

```
for (k = 0; k < cols; k++)
{
    numbers[k] = new int[cols];
    arraytranspose[k] = new int[cols];
}
```

And this set the first `cols` values in these arrays, but they are `rows` values in size. So, if `rows` is less than `cols`, this results in memory corruption and undefined behavior, as the shown code writes to values of the array that do not exist.

This is the first obvious flaw in the shown code that's obvious from a cursory inspection, but it's likely there are other similar flaws as well; they generally result from unsafe programming practices like the ones shown here, like manual memory allocation, and lack of bounds checking. Modern C++ code offers plenty of safe programming practices, like using `std::vector`s to manage dynamically-sized arrays, and iterators.

Simply fixing this specific bug will be merely a bandaid, even if it turns out to be the only bug fix. Your real, long-term fix is to rewrite this entire code, and start using modern C++ containers, containers, and algorithms, which, when used correctly, will eliminate most opportunities for this entire class of bugs.